# Change default entrance behaviour of wordpress thickbox

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, thickbox

I am showing a contact form in wordpress default thickbox, and its working fine. As thickbox is triggered by link with `class="thickbox"` by default it just set css of div (to be shown in thickbox) from display none to display block;

What desired is instead of default behaviour it should fadeIn (Looks better !)

So far, I got the following -

```
<?php
    add_Action('wp_head','enquiry_popup');
    function enquiry_popup(){ ?>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('.thickbox').click(function (event){
                event.preventDefault();
                jQuery('#pr_enquiry_form').fadeIn('slow');
            })

        });
        </script>
<?php } ?>
```

`event.preventDefault();` not seems to work here.
also `jQuery('#pr_enquiry_form').fadeIn('slow');` is not affecting anything

`pr_enquiry_form` is Id of div I am loading in the thickbox

Comment: But what's not working exactly? What does JavaScript say? Could you perform an `alert('Test');` to see if it's listening to the `.click()`?

Comment: I already did alert test and its working, Not getting any js errors in console

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` will only work on an element that's expected to do something (like an `<a>`) - Not sure what element it is listening to at the moment. Can you see `#pr_enquiry_form` in the DOM when you inspect it? What new CSS Rules have been applied once the `fadeIn()` starts?

Comment: It loads a whole new html document in thickbox so cant see #pr_enquiry_form

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` won't change the expected Thickbox behaviour if that's what you're hoping. So you're calling an iframe with `TB_iframe`?

Comment: You're probably better off integrating jQuery Modal/Dialog by the way, considering `Thickbox` is increasingly becoming deprecated.